# Git create a branch based on a feature branch ahead of master

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch that's been pulled from staging. There's a production branch that's ahead of master that I want to base my feature branch off of.

```
git ls-remote
```

doesn't show a reference to the branch I need to pull from. Do I need to set a new master or rebase to do this? I'm looking for a way to keep the master as it is (staging) and be able to pull from branches ahead (prod).

**Edit:**

I've attempted to checkout the production branch itself but it's throwing an error:

```
->  git checkout release-0000
error: pathspec 'release-0000' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

**More Edit:**

So while `git ls-remote` didn't show the remote branch I was trying to pull from--`release-0000`, `git branch -a` and `git branch -r` contained the name of the branch it the list. My attempt to pull/checkout the branch by its name, `release-000` didn't work, I'm assuming because it was lacking its "full path" which is `origin/release-000.` When referred to the branch name including `origin,` git recognized the production branch and I was able to checkout.

Comment: Can you do `git branch` and `git branch -r` and show us the results?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it's a long list, but `git branch` shows only those feature branches I created off of master. `git branch -r` shows all the branches, including the production branch I need to pull from.

Comment: And you're sure you've spelled the branch name correctly? Git doesn't seem to agree with you when you say the branch exists. Can you at least show the exact branch name listed from `git branch -r` that you want to check out? (and by that I mean to execute the command and then copy and paste the name here)

Comment: Use `git branch -a` to view all branches.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ah, so the branch name I was seeing from github page's dropdown menu was `release-000` but I followed the name convention that was visible in `git branch -r` which was `origin/release-0000` and that did the trick! I am able to create a new branch from here and push/pr to the production branch afterwards?

Comment: @viviboox3 Yes.

Comment: out of curiosity--and because I'm still trying to understand git workflow, why won't `release-000` work but I must refer to it as `origin/release-000`?

Comment: @viviboox3 The short answer is that you do not have a local branch named `release-000`.

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using OSX and bash

Comment: I suspect that you have multiple remotes each with a branch named `release-000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not already have a local version of the feature branch, you need to create it with

```
$ git checkout origin/feature
$ git branch feature
```

or as a shortcut

```
$ git checkout -b feature origin/feature
```

Now you can create a new branch with and check it out with

```
$ git branch <new-branch-name>
$ git checkout <new-branch-name>
```

or

```
$ git checkout -b <new-branch-name> feature
```

Note that `feature` on the end of the above command is optional if you already did `git checkout feature`. However, the version I used above is useful when you are not currently on the branch which you want to use as the base for a new branch.

**Here's a head scratcher:**

According to [the documentation for `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt):

> If  is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it ) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

So the fact that `git checkout <branch>` failed for you tells me that you most likely have two remotes with the same branch name.

Comment: Is it just a matter of which branches are available on your local repo? i.e. `/origin/<branch-name>` refer to remote, and `<branch-name>` refers to local?

Comment: @viviboox3 See my edited answer. Also, I suggest reading about so-called "remote tracking branches".

Comment: @viviboox3 And another edit with some clues why your attempts with `git checkout` failed.

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout the production branch and create a new branch from there.
So that all commits in production branch which is ahead of master is pulled to that new branch

Comment: I am unable to checkout production branch. It tells me `error: pathspec 'release-0000' did not match any file(s) known to git.` And the branch isn't visible when I try to ls remote branches

Comment: Please paste all the branches available in your repo, local. So that i can see
git branch -r - to see remote branches
git branch -l - to see local branches

Comment: so the branch name I was seeing from github page's dropdown menu was `release-000` but I followed the name convention that was visible in `git branch -r` which was `origin/release-0000` and that did the trick!

Comment: It looks like you didn't pulled release-0000 branch to your local repo